# Change settings of LAV Filters at DirectShow

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am able to render a RTSP video stream (rtsp://10.0.0.11:7070/stream/channel1) with following graph:

> LAV Splitter -> LAV Video Decoder -> Video Renderer

When I open the RTSP stream with VLC, I set Caching to 300 ms and video gets play smoothly with 300 ms delay. But my graph renders the stream with 1 second delay. How can I change buffer/cache value of LAV filters? Or alternatively how can I reduce delay when using LAV filters?

Thank you